# Saving Variables on app exit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, variables

I have a simple iPhone app in swift with multiple views and a list of 5 different items that have variables attached to them that get passed to each new view no matter where the user is in the app.

Example:

```
    var Peron1 = String()
    var Person1Age = Int()
    var Person1Switch = Bool()
```

(Imagine that but for 5 people)

Basically I want to program the app so when the user quits and returns to the app the variables they have entered into the app already are restored and then can continue to be manipulated. What is the best way to do this? Also I don't want to include a save or restore button.

Comment: Save them whenever they change...

Answer (score 8):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` and save the variable-values in it:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(Person1, forKey: "Person1")
defaults.setInteger(Person1Age, forKey: "Person1Age")
defaults.setBool(Person1Switch, forKey: "Person1Switch")
```

Then you can get it later, even after an app restart like that:

```
defaults.stringForKey("Person1")
defaults.integerForKey("Person1Age")
defaults.boolForKey("Person1Switch")
```

As you see you can access it by using the fitting methods for your datatype.

Comment: thanks! This worked with the addition of some if statements to make sure there was a value stored in the defaults before loading them